# He doesn't have breakfast every day

Tags: grammar

1. He doesn't have breakfast every day.
2. He doesn't have breakfast at all.
3. He sometimes eats breakfast, and he sometimes doesn't eat breakfast.

---

Does #1 mean #2 or #3?

Answer (score 1):

#1 means #3.

"He dosen't have breakfast" would mean #2.

"Every day he donsn't have breakfast" would also mean #2.

The negative in 'dosen't' is applied to 'every day'.

Another way to frame the question would be:
"He has breakfast, but not every day".

Answer (score 0):

> **He does not have breakfast everyday** means He has sometimes breakfast.
>
> **He does not have breakfast at all means He never has break fast**.
>
> **He sometimes eats breakfast** means he sometimes does not eat breakfast.

only the second sentence means that   he does never have breakfast.

**The first and the third sentence mean almost the same.**

Comment: “He does not have breakfast every day” does **not** mean he sometimes has breakfast.  It’s ambiguous. He might never have breakfast.

Comment: I do not think so.He does not eat breakfast everyday does not mean that he never eats breakfast.

Comment: I do not think so.He does not eat breakfast everyday does not mean that he never eats breakfast.

Comment: In fact, it is ambiguous.  You can’t draw a conclusion about how often the person eats breakfast— only that it’s not **every** day.

Comment: If it is not everyday means  some days

Comment: There is an idiomatic phrase “it is not every day that” which [means **rarely**. (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%20is%20not%20every%20day). But that doesn’t apply here.   This is a simple logic statement where you’re making a logic fallacy called [“inverse error.” See Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent)

Comment: .. or perhaps the [“Converse fallacy” — see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).  He might never eat breakfast: you don’t know.